# Mongoose (MongodDB) find ObjectId in array of ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using nodejs, mongoose (so mongodb as a database) and javascript.

I have a collection named A which some examples are the following:

```
{
   "item": "Kitchen",
   "location": "New York",
   "ids" : [ ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a1121a649a"), ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a1121a649b"), ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a112a649c")]
}
{
   "item": "Bathroom",
   "location": "New York",
   "ids" : [ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a112a649c")]
}
{
   "item": "Living Room",
   "location": "New York",
   "ids" : [ ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a1121a649a"), ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a1121a649b")]
}
```

The ids are the references to another collection which I will name B. An example would in the collection B is the following:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a1121a649a"),
  "name" : "George",
  "Age": 12,
  "Nationality": "English"
}
```

I would like to be able to find all items in collection A which have `ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a1121a649a")` in the ids array.

Excepted Result: `["Kitchen", "Living Room"]`

Does anyone have an idea how I could processed?

Comment: can you add your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method,

- `$match` search id in `ids` array
- `$group` all item in `items` array

```
db.A.aggregate([
  { $match: { ids: ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a1121a649a") } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      items: { $push: "$item" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iUJRp1mOAEh)

---

You can use [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) method,

```
let result = await db.A.find(
  { ids: ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a1121a649a") },
  { _id: 0, item: 1 }
);
let items = result.map(obj => obj.item);
console.log(items);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6ulMEByoR_r)

Answer (score 1):

Mongo allows you to query arrays the same way you query a none-array field.

It also has a built in [distinct](https://www.google.com/search?q=distinct&oq=distinct&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5j69i60l2.3823j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) function to fetch unique values from a query.

```
db.collection.distinct("item", {ids: ObjectId("5f6dce24021e15a1121a649a")})
```